# Variable taking another variable's name as its value - MySQL

Tags: mysql, variables

```
SET @session = '1'; SET @session = '[@session]';
SELECT @session;
```

This should print -: `[1]` but it is printing `[@session]`;

Whats the problem? Thanks for help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is as expected. `[@session]` was the last value that was set to variable `@session`.

```
SET @session = '1';           -- <<== first value
SET @session = '[@session]';  -- <<== second value (overrides the first value)
SELECT @session;
```

i think you mean,

```
SET @session = '1';           
SET @session = CONCAT('[', @session, ']');  
SELECT @session;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/9369)

Comment: But i want `[1]`. How to get this?